# How to create an asynchronous confirmation box from an ajax function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await, promise

I am trying to create a custom confirmation box that will run asynchronously from an ajax function that will call a hidden Delete button in the C# code behind, but I can't seem to get it to wait properly.  I simply want it to bring up a confirmation box and then wait to process anything else until the user has chosen yes or no. I am using a Promise for waiting.  However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  The hidden Delete button click should be the last thing that happens if the user has clicked yes, but the code is not getting into that block. I am sure there is something very simple that I am missing.  The following is the code that I am using:

```
<div id="confirm" class="confirm">
    <div class="message">The project name already exists!  Do you wish to delete the project?</div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <button id="true_btn" class="true_btn">Yes</button>
        <button id="false_btn" class="false_btn">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

function checkDirectory(projectName) {
        var onError = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["checkDirUrl"] %>" + "/" + projectName,
            //async: false,
            success: async function (result) {
                if (result === "folder exists")
                {
                    //if (confirm('The project name already exists!  Do you wish to delete the project?')) {
                    if (await deleteDemo() === 1) {
                        alert('After deleteDemo');
                        $("#<%= btnHiddenDelete.ClientID %>").click();
                    } else {
                        onError = true;
                        $("#error").text("Project name already exists!");
                    }
                } else {
                    window.location = ("/Database.aspx");
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                onError = true;
                $("#error").text("Error accessing project folder!");
            }
        });
        return onError;
    }

async function confirmationBox() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var confirmation_modal = $("#confirm");
            var true_el = $("#true_btn");
            var false_el = $("#false_btn");

            alert('In confirmationBox');

            confirmation_modal.show();

            true_el.click(function() {
                alert('yes');
                resolve(1);
            });

            false_el.click(function() {
                alert('no');
                resolve(0);
            });
        });
    }

    async function deleteDemo() {
        var result = await confirmationBox();
        alert(result);
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You are not awaiting the call. `if (await deleteDemo() === 1) {`

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I also get multiple syntax errors in that function when I put the await in place.

Comment: Did you make the function `async` when using `await`?

Comment: If the design specs allow, you could save yourself a ton of trouble by using the built-in `confirm()` function.

Comment: Yes, I did make the function async.

Comment: @Quasipickle, I originally used the confirm() function, but the specs call for something that looks better.

Comment: @Samball, I updated my version of jQuery from 2.2.4 to 3.6.0 and now I am able to using async on the success function of checkDirectory and await for the deleteDemo function.  This gets me into the deleteDemo function properly.  I have updated the code that included to reflect this change.  However, there are multiple syntax errors and most importantly the hidden Delete with the C# code behind is still not getting called.  It appears there is an unnecessary page refresh that is happening.